# Access cosmos db through azure synapse analytics notebook using system assigned managed identity linked service

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-managed-identity, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-notebooks, mssparkutils

i have made a linked service for cosmos db no sql using system assigned managed identity as auth type and linked service is published as well. Now when i access this linked service from synapse analytics notebook using below code it gives me this error:POST failed with 'Bad Request' (400) and message: {"result":"DependencyError","errorId":"BadRequest","errorMessage":"[Code=AuthTypeNotSupported, Target=LS_MI_CosmosDb, Message=Linked Service Auth Type not supported]}.
my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
# Read CSV data into a DataFrame
csv_file_path = "file path"
data_frame = pd. read_csv(csv_file_path, encoding='latin1')
# Convert DataFrame to JSON
json_data = data_frame.to_json(orient='records')

# Initialize Cosmos DB client with managed identity
cosmosdb_endpoint = "endpoint"
database_name = "SNM"
container_name = "AliTest"
credential = mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds("Linked service") // error on this line

client = CosmosClient(cosmosdb_endpoint, credential=credential)

# Get a reference to the Cosmos DB container
container = client.get_database_client(database_name).get_container_client(container_name)

# Insert JSON data into Cosmos DB container
for item in json.loads(json_data):
    container.upsert_item(item)
```

i have tried every way but still encountering AuthTypeNotSupported error.

Comment: Can you check whether the above authentication working with Hardcoded Connection string from cosmos? or that also resulting same error?

Comment: yes it is working when we create linked service with key/ connection string it only gives error on managed identity

Comment: what about the testing connection of cosmos linked service? Is that successful?

Comment: yeah test connection was successful too

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK**, `mssparkutils.credentials.getConnectionStringOrCreds()` might not work for the Cosmos linked service of Managed identity.

For cosmos db linked service(with managed identity), we don’t follow the general process of assigning roles through UI in cosmos IAM.

We need to assign the roles like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac) which is a different way. This might be the reason for the error.

As a workaround, you can try with `Account key` authentication and for security, you can use Key vault.

[image]
`

Comment: yes i actually assigned role this way, but i came to a conclusion that you cannot access cosmos db via managed identity in azure notebook, instead you can store the credentials in key vault and access that key vault via managed identity. this is the workaround that i used.

Answer (score 0):

yes i actually assigned role this way, but i came to a conclusion that you cannot access cosmos db via managed identity in azure notebook, instead you can store the credentials in key vault and access that key vault via managed identity. this is the workaround that i used.